# Como puedo saber los datos de una API PHP?

Tags: php, api

Una pregunta tonta como puedo saber los datos de esta Api usando PHP esta funcion `foreach` se me esta olvidando como se usa pero bueno lo que quiero es saber el  `name` y `price_usd`

```
$tick = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/');
$url = $tick;

//$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($tick, TRUE);


    foreach ( $json as $data ) {
        foreach ( $data as $value ) { 
            $name = $data[0]["name"];
            echo $name;
                echo '<br>';
            $price_usd = $data[0]["price_usd"];
            echo $price_usd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eso dependerá siempre de cómo venga el objeto que responde la API, o  sea, si es un array (o un json) simple, si es un array bidimensional (json anidado)..., etc. Si muestras la estructura de la variable `$json` entonces podrías tener una respuesta más precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas el segundo foreach, en `$data` ya viene la información de cada uno de tus elementos

```
foreach ( $json as $data ) {
    echo $data['name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $data['price_usd'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```